# jquery - starting with element passed into function via this pointer

Tags: jquery

I am very new to jQuery so this may be a really stupid question. :-)  I'm trying to get something like the following working:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JQuery test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("jquery", "1"); // Load jQuery

      function DoSomething(link)
      {
        $(link).after('<div>hello world!</div>');
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript: DoSomething(this);">Click!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Right now that doesn't seem to do anything.  But if I change the line to:

```
$('a').after('<div>hello world!</div>');
```

Then a DIV does get inserted.  However, I want to use an element passed into the function to control where the element gets inserted.  Basically, I can't figure out how to start a jQuery query based on an element passed in to a function via the "this" pointer.

Thanks for the help,

~ Justin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jQuery, you can generally avoid inserting any javascript into your HTML at all, eg: `href="javascript: ..."` or `href="#" onclick="..."`. A neater way is to write a query to target that element and apply the behaviour from there. The simplest way to target the element is to give it an ID, but you could use any method you like.

```
<a href="#" id="myLink">Click!</a>
```

and your jQuery:

```
$('#myLink').click(function() {
    $(this).after("<div>hello world!</div>");
});
```

Inside the [event handling functions](http://docs.jquery.com/Events), `this` refers to the DOM element that was targeted by the event.

If you want to get a jQuery object from an element - just pass it to the constructor:

```
$(domElement)
```

You might be having issues because of the way you're calling the handler. Try changing your link to this style:

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomething(this)">
```

Just remember to make `doSomething()` return false

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I suppose I could do something like that.  There are going to be multiple links on the page that need to call the function, so I would have to assign a class to them or something, and attach the function to all links of that class.  But, I would like to see my question answered just so I can understand jQuery more.

Comment: Changing from 

    <a href="javascript: DoSomething(this);">Click!</a>

to
    
    <a href="#" onclick="doSomething(this)">

*does* work.  Any idea why that makes a difference?

Comment: using `javascript:` runs in a different context to the `on*` handlers. I suspect that if you use `href=javascript:blah(this)`, then "this" will be the `Window` object.

Answer (score 1):

> Changing from `<a href="javascript: DoSomething(this);">Click!</a>` to `<a href="#" onclick="doSomething(this)">` does work.

`this` is only meaningful in JavaScript functions. Event handlers like `onclick` are a kind of function.

javascript: pseudo-URLs are not functions. They are not executed in the context of any object on the page. They are just a string. Clicking the link is the same as typing that string into the web browser's address bar. Consequently `this` will give the default value `window`, the global object, which is always passed when there is no particular `this` object.

javascript: pseudo-URLs are a complete disaster and should never be used for anything (well, except bookmarklets). The `onclick` form is better, though you should remember to add `return false;` so that it doesn't follow the `#` link and jump to the top of the page.

(A non-link element with onclick, or a styled button may be more appropriate than a link, depending on what the Something is that DoSomething is doing.)